# Rake Stats task failure with code_statistics file missing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

Have a legacy application built on Rails 3.2.16, Ruby 1.9.3 which is being assessed for updates.  Apart from the obvious in that it's running on outdated versions of both Ruby and Rails, I'm stuck with an error when trying to gather the stats.

When executing the command:

```
rake stats
```

I'm getting the error:

```
rake stats
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- code_statistics
```

This is also correlated via the 'Rails Console' whereby issuing the command `require 'code_statistics'` also produces a similar error.

Now I can confirm the following

- Rake task exists as shown by the `rake -T` giving command output of `rake stats                             # Report code statistics (KLOCs, etc...`
- `CodeStatistics` class is in the *railities* library

I suspect that it's a path or file issue with potentially an environment setting that I'm missing Rails 3.2.

Any suggestions ?

Regards
Grant

Answer (score 1):

Ok - so solved the problem. It was a path issue as first suspected.

After some digging in this legacy system I'm reviewing there were path changes made in `rspec.rake` and `cuke.rake` files which indicated a parent directory. Changing the path

**from**:

```
require 'code_statistics'
```

**to**

```
require 'rails/code_statistics'
```

has now resolved the issue such that `rake stats` gives the usual results.